# How to print the execution time of Merge Sort

Tags: c, mergesort, execution-time

[sample program output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pAem.png)

I have here a program that lets the user enter the N of the randomly generated numbers. Now, I am having a problem with printing it. It prints more than execution time.

```
void merge_sort(int i, int j, int a[], int aux[]) {

    start = clock();
    if (j <= i) {
      // if the subsection is empty or a single element
      return;
    }
    int mid = (i + j) / 2;

    // left sub-array is a[i .. mid]
    // right sub-array is a[mid + 1 .. j]

    merge_sort(i, mid, a, aux);         // sort the left sub-array recursively
    merge_sort(mid + 1, j, a, aux);     // sort the right sub-array recursively

    int pointer_left = i;               // pointer_left points to the beginning of the left sub-array
    int pointer_right = mid + 1;        // pointer_right points to the beginning of the right sub-array
    int k;                              // k is the loop counter

    // we loop from i to j to fill each element of the final merged array
    for (k = i; k <= j; k++) {
        if (pointer_left == mid + 1) {                      // left pointer has reached the limit
            aux[k] = a[pointer_right];
            pointer_right++;
        } else if (pointer_right == j + 1) {                // right pointer has reached the limit
            aux[k] = a[pointer_left];
            pointer_left++;
        } else if (a[pointer_left] < a[pointer_right]) {     // pointer left points to smaller element
            aux[k] = a[pointer_left];
            pointer_left++;
        } else {        // pointer right points to smaller element
            aux[k] = a[pointer_right];
            pointer_right++;
        }
    }
    // copy the elements from aux[] to a[]
    for (k = i; k <= j; k++) {
        a[k] = aux[k];
    }
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("TIME: %f\n", cpu_time_used);
}

// main method
int main(){

    int size, i;
    printf("Enter N: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int array[size];
    int aux[size];
    if(size <= 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error!\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % MAXRANGE;

    }

    printf("\nMerge Sorted: ");
    merge_sort(0, size - 1, array, aux);
    printArray(array, size);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know where to put the `clock()` calls or the computation of the execution time. Is it after printing?

Comment: Don't put a `printf` in `merge_sort` itself. `printf` is generally slow. It will disturb the timing. Either only do `clock` [recommended: `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)`] by the original caller. Or, have the time difference value stored into a global array that you print after leaving the sort routine.

Comment: Your `merge_sort()` function is recursive — so you get times for the subordinate calls as well as the outermost one, which is not what you usually want (and the printing in the subordinate calls slows the sorting horribly).  Wrap `merge_sort()` in a function `timed_merge_sort()` which starts the clock, runs the `merge_sort()` and then stops the clock and prints the results.  The main `merge_sort()` code should do no printing at all (except in debug mode, when timing isn't relevant).

Comment: Don't post images of plain text — include the text as 'code' in the question.  If you're fussy about appearances, you can add a line `<!-- language: lang-none -->` (with blank lines before and after it) immediately before the text to suppress colouring of the data, though that isn't crucial.

Comment: How about *before* and *after* `merge_sort(0, size - 1, array, aux);`?

Comment: What about using a header only benchmark library? A small Google search probably bring some options.

Comment: regarding: `cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` This can give an incorrect elapsed time.  Suggest: `cpu_time_used = difftime( end, start) / CLOCKS_PER_SECOND;`  as that properly handles the negative values currently returned from `clock()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some guidelines:

- include `<time.h>`
- get the current time with `clock_t start = clock()` just before the function you want to time.
- compute the elapsed time with `clock_t elapsed = clock() - start;` just after the end of the function.
- do not produce output during the timed routine.
- avoid producing any output before the function you want to time.
- output the elapsed time converted to a number of milliseconds this way:

  ```
  printf("Elapsed time: %12.3f\n", elapsed * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  ```

You have followed these guidelines in your code, but you should move the timing outside `mergesort` because this function is recursive.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void merge_sort(int i, int j, int a[], int aux[]) {
    if (j <= i) {
        // if the subsection is empty or a single element
        return;
    }
    int mid = (i + j) / 2;

    // left sub-array is a[i .. mid]
    // right sub-array is a[mid + 1 .. j]

    merge_sort(i, mid, a, aux);         // sort the left sub-array recursively
    merge_sort(mid + 1, j, a, aux);     // sort the right sub-array recursively

    int pointer_left = i;               // pointer_left points to the beginning of the left sub-array
    int pointer_right = mid + 1;        // pointer_right points to the beginning of the right sub-array
    int k;                              // k is the loop counter

    // we loop from i to j to fill each element of the final merged array
    for (k = i; k <= j; k++) {
        if (pointer_left == mid + 1) {  // left pointer has reached the limit
            aux[k] = a[pointer_right];
            pointer_right++;
        } else if (pointer_right == j + 1) {  // right pointer has reached the limit
            aux[k] = a[pointer_left];
            pointer_left++;
        } else if (a[pointer_left] < a[pointer_right]) {  // pointer left points to smaller element
            aux[k] = a[pointer_left];
            pointer_left++;
        } else {                        // pointer right points to smaller element
            aux[k] = a[pointer_right];
            pointer_right++;
        }
    }
    // copy the elements from aux[] to a[]
    for (k = i; k <= j; k++) {
        a[k] = aux[k];
    }
}

#define MAXRANGE 1000

// main method
int main() {
    clock_t start, elapsed1, elapsed2;
    int size, i;

    printf("Enter N: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1 || size <= 0) {
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int array[size];
    int aux[size];

    start = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % MAXRANGE;
    }
    elapsed1 = clock() - start;

    start = clock();
    merge_sort(0, size - 1, array, aux);
    elapsed2 = clock() - start;

    printf("initialisation time: %12.3f\n",
           (double)elapsed1 * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("    merge sort time: %12.3f\n",
           (double)elapsed2 * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i - 1] > array[i])
            break;
    }

    if (i == size) {
        printf("array sorted\n");
    } else {
        printf("sort error: array[%i] = %d > array[%i] = %d\n",
               i - 1, array[i - 1], i, array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter N: 500000
initialisation time:        5.783
    merge sort time:       45.890
array sorted
```

Comment: Thanks, btw, can I reuse the start = clock() and the elapsed time variables to another sorting function?, or do I need to deallocate or clear it first?

Comment: also, is it okay if i have 0.00 time in insertion sort with 10 as the number of elements. I got 0.01 with 100 number of elements

Comment: @fetucinni: The value printed is a number of miiliseconds. Sorting 10 elements can be done in less than half a micro second, causing an output of `0.000`.  The precision of the `clock()` function also depends on the target system: some have a very precise `clock()` function, with micro-second precision, while others only measure milliseconds or more coarse units. Check the value of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` on your system.

Comment: @fetucinni: in the `main()` function, I reuse the `start` variable but use separate `elapsed1` and `elapsed2` variables to track the initialization and sort times and avoid printing before calling `merge_sort()`. These variables are just integer variables.

Comment: Copy! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some guidelines:

For getting execution time:

```
include <time.h>
int main(){
    struct timeval stop,start;
    int arr[10000];
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    mergeSort(arr, 100);
    gettimeofday(&stop,NULL);
    printf("Time taken for Quick sort is: %ld microseconds\n", 
        (stop.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000000+stop.tv_usec-start.tv_usec);
}
```